# Two linux OS at a time

Tags: software-center, fedora

If i install ubuntu 12.04 alongside fedora 17 and
If i install some applications in ubuntu and then later i login my pc with fedora will the applications will be available for me in fedora or do i have to restart my pc with ubuntu to access those applications.need help

Comment: You actually can run apps in your Fedora system from your Ubuntu system and vice versa, by [`chroot`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/chroot.8.html)ing. I'm posting this as a comment rather than an answer because a full answer explaining how to do this must explain how to set up the Xauthority correctly so that GUI applications work right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu is based on Debian Package Management while Fedora is based on RPM .While installing packages for Particular Os (Ubuntu or Fedora) they are only accessible in the Os you installed. Also different methods are used for Installing packages in both of them.
For Example -You cant Install the IOs app for Android , unless it is made available or created for Android.

Basically You cant use packages from Different Os'es. They are TWO DIFFERENT OS with Different Identities . you have to do little research on both of them , if you are really interested in using them.

Comment: what about if i use pinguy with ubuntu or fedora with redhat

Comment: Pinguy Os will be compatible since it is Based on ubuntu. Fedora on other hand uses Latest Built and Newer versions of packages while RHEL uses stable versions specifically tested for stability and usability. 
Better Idea would be, download source tar packages of the softwares and compile it individually for your system, it will also add-up  a learning experience and plus you can save your Bandwidth .